# MySQL: Unable to reset admin password; --skip-grant-tables disallowing ALTER USER

Tags: mysql

Somehow the `root` password on my local installation of MySQL (Ver 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))) isn't what I thought it was. Okay, quick search reveals that the step to reset it is to stop MySQL, restart it with `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` and go in and change the password. Okay, no big deal.

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option 
so it cannot execute this statement
```

What?!? I'm running with the `--skip-grant-tables` option **precisely because** I was told to do so. Okay, let me try the other way:

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('')
WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(''), 
plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root' AND Host='%'' at line 1
```

Why does everyone say to use `--skip-grant-tables` if `ALTER USER` doesn't work under it? What is wrong with the `UPDATE` statement? And what's the best way to fix this situation?

(BTW, this server isn't and won't be exposed outside of our organization, so I don't need the lecture about the password being empty.)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html also says you need to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` before you can run account-management statements. There are also alternative instructions for using `mysqld --init-file=<filename>` to run an ALTER USER statement on startup. I suggest you re-read that page as the current guide for resetting the root password.

Comment: "Why does everyone say", more misguided people that copy too much of what might have worked before rather than reading official documentation. How did official documentation loose popularity to internet here-say? Also ranting against "why does everyone" pre-emptively,  `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` isn't needed after `ALTER USER` or any user modification SQL (that isn't a hack involving the `mysql.user` table directly). This is also in the manual (by its absence).

Comment: Congratulations on finding the solution to every problem in the manuals.

Answer (score 0):

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';
```

Restart machine.